# reason 'uitable data source is not set' error in iOS 8.0.2

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a view having table to display list of contacts and another view for its detail. Issue is when I open contacts-view then it works fine; but when i open it, go to detail view of contact and press back then it gets crashes.
It shows me error like below.

**Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6048.**
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource is not set'**

I have observed this in iOS 8.0.2 which works fine on iOS 7.0. Is there anything related to iOS version.?

Same thing is happening in Message module. Here I am posting code snippet.

**MessageListController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = FALSE;

    instanceMessageList.delegate = self;
    instanceMessageList.dataSource = self;
    [self setNavigationBarView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self setEditing:FALSE animated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [instanceMessageList release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**MessageListViewController.h**

```
@interface MessageListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, MessageDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Instance variable declaration

    IBOutlet UITableView *instanceMessageList;
    IBOutlet UILabel *noMessages;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Instance variable property declaration

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *instanceMessageList;

@end
```

Comment: Post some related code. How are you setting `dataSource` and `delegates` to tableview and are you using arc or non-arc?

Comment: any more code required, ask me freely.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if i set datasource in viewWillAppear `self.tableView.delegate = self;` then where should I again set it to nil.? my issue is when I am navigating back tableview goes to update it but at that time only i am setting nil.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution. Actual error is not here in above code. Error occurs in detail view in viewWillDisappear() method.
Root cause is: when back button is pressed, keyboard is hidden which causes UITableView to execute **CellForRowAtIndexPath()** method and at that time and in **ViewWillDisappear()** method I was setting table's datasource to nil. which caused error.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the view is getting reloaded and the dataSource is upset somewhere. Inside your Contacts Controller `-viewDidLoad` method add the following code:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: i have done this. that's why it is working for the first when i open contacts view. but not after coming back from detail.

Comment: Ok, I suppose, I could solve your problem if your add some code to your question.