# UIPickerView crash when updating width

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, uipickerview

I am using six `UIPickerView` in my application. So based on the selection value from one picker other pickers will display and they will rearrange to fit the screen.

On iOS 10 this is working correctly, but when running on iOS 9 app crashed with

> reason: `NSInternalInconsistencyException` UITableView dataSource is not set

I tried by commenting the codes changing the `UIPickerView` width then the app works without any crash.

Any idea about this issue?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26136039/reason-uitable-data-source-is-not-set-error-in-ios-8-0-2

Comment: I didn't have any tableview on my view. So I think this s not my issue.

Comment: Have you tried by calling picker view `reloadAllComponents()` and view's `layoutIfNeeded()` methods?

Comment: Yes, tried but no change same issue again.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for that? If it works fine in iOS 10 and on iOS 9 might be a racing issue

Comment: can you try your UIpickerView with a static array (So you can judge if the reasons of the error)